# Calculator Program that can evaluate multiple arithmetic expressions

Tags: c++

Write a better version of the calculator, calc2.cpp, that can evaluate multiple arithmetic expressions. Let’s use the semicolon symbol that must be used at the end of each expression in the input.

Assuming that the input file formulas.txt looks as follows:

15 ;

10 + 3 + 0 + 25 ;

5 + 6 - 7 - 8 + 9 + 10 - 11 ;

When we run the program with that input, the output should evaluate all of the expressions and print them each on its own line:

$ ./calc2 < formulas.txt

15

38

4

It only runs the prints the answer to the first line I have no idea how to fix it. Please help me, thank you!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
char opr;         //character
int  value;       //New value.
int sum = 0;
cin >> sum; //first value is the sum.
while(true) //infinite loop
{ 
cin >> opr;
if(opr == ';')
{
  cout << sum<< endl;//prints the results when ; is reached
  break;     //exits the loop
}
cin >> value;
switch (opr)
{
 case '+': 
  sum += value;
  break;
 case '-':
  sum -= value;
  break;
  default:
  break;
}

}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: `char opr ='+' || '-' || ';';  //character` why do you store `1`  in this variable in such a fancy way.

Comment: This is not a free debugging service. You should learn to use a debugger to fix bugs in future programs instead of asking it here. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ Also, you really should fix your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I re-ordered some operations:

- First, if this is the first number in a new expression, save it as the "sum" value
- then read an operand value
- if that operand value is not ';' (end of expression), read in a new value
- perform the operation according to the entered operation character, print sum on ";" and reset values
- also indented the entire code correctly to make it readable

Note: This program does no error checking and assumes that it is given a well-formed expression. Giving it non-confirming input will make it crash/do weird things.

Outputs

```
C:\Users\Maxi\Desktop> g++ -o test test.cpp
C:\Users\Maxi\Desktop> test.exe
15 ;
15
10 + 3 + 0 + 25 ;
38
5 + 6 - 7 - 8 + 9 + 10 - 11 ;
4
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char opr;
    int value; //New value.
    int sum = 0;
    bool firstValueSet = false;
    while (true) //infinite loop
    {
        if(!firstValueSet) { 
            cin >> sum ; 
            firstValueSet = true;
            //cout << "Sum is now " << sum << endl;
        }
        //Then an operand
        cin >> opr;
        //Then the number
        if( opr != ';')
            cin >> value; 
        //cout << "operand " << opr << " value " << value << endl;
        switch (opr) {
        case '+':
            sum += value;
            //cout << "Adding " << value << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            sum -= value;
            break;
        case ';': //End of expression
            cout << sum << endl;
            sum = 0; //Reset
            firstValueSet = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```